# LoadBalancer in Pending State

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I tried to deploy a reactapp service on kubernetes but the loadbalancer keeps coming in pending state.

I am on free trial status on GCP. Could this be the reason??

Comment: Hi @Oluseun and welcome to Stack Overflow!  You probably should review [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, this question needs more detail about your configuration (e.g. the yaml files) and possibly the configuration of your cluster (e.g. instance sizes, etc).  Otherwise, its hard to give a good answer.

Comment: kubectl describe svc service_name

Comment: If you have added a valid credit card to your account, then this is not the problem. You have $300 in credits that can be used for any GCP service. Edit your question and provide details, otherwise, we can only guess what you did and what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

GKE sets up the kubernetes nodes for you. The load balancer should work straight out. Compare your yaml with the one below. And check for its status running `kubectl get svc`. Are you getting a ClusterIP IP? What happens if you change the type to NodePort, is you app reachable through the nodes IPS?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: example-service
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: example-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: "port"
    port: 8000
    targetPort: 8000
  selector:
    app: example-service
```